# Javascript Callback with Parameters

Tags: javascript, callback

I have seen numerous questions posted that refer to passing parameters to callback functions so I apologize for posting yet another but I am fairly new to JavaScript and have a question.

I have created two blocks of code that pass data to a callback function but do it in slightly different ways and I was hoping for some feedback on if there is a preferred method or if I am even doing it correctly.  Are there advantages to using one method over the other.

Here are the two code blocks.

In this first block I am passing the callback function along with the data as a single parameter.

```js
function CreateGreeting_A(callback)
{
    callback();
}

let GreetingAfternoon_A = function (varMessage)
{
    console.log('The greeting message is: ' + varMessage);
}

CreateGreeting_A(function () { GreetingAfternoon_A('Have a lovely Day') });
```

In the second block I am passing the callback function along with the data as a two separate parameters.

```js
function CreateGreeting_B(varGreeting, callback)
{
    callback(varGreeting);
}

let Greeting_Afternoon_B = function (v1)
{
    console.log('The greeting message is: ' + v1);
}

CreateGreeting_B('Good Afternoon', Greeting_Afternoon_B);
```

Comment: Of course most of it is opinion and use case based but I'd prefer second over first as in the second impl, I can see that createGreeting method is taking one param greeting and a callback and generating a greeting. Its more readable

Comment: Hard to tell what you're getting at here since these are somewhat contrived examples. Could you give us a more realistic example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: This is not really on topic here. Preference will vary based on the context and is primarily opinion based.